# Full-Text search on a table column issue

Tags: t-sql

I have a Table that I want to search its title(nvarchar(max)) column.

But I am getting an error when I create an index over the title column so I can enable Full Text search on it.

I am going to use the Contains keyword to do the job.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Comment: Did you create a catalogue for the full text index? Which error do you receive when creating it?

Comment: No, I didn't create a Catalogue for the full text index.

Comment: When I create the index over the column Title, I get an error stating that you cannot create an index over a column of this type...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say in the comments

> When I create the index over the
>   column Title, I get an error stating
>   that you cannot create an index over a
>   column of this type

This sounds like you are trying to create a regular index on it not a full text index. Right click the table in SSMS and choose "Full Text Index" to set up full text indexing.

If this option is greyed out you might need to run `exec sp_fulltext_database 'enable'` first.